# In Windows 7 event log, what is a "Source"?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, event-log

I'm coding a simple application in C# and writing somethings to the Event Log.  I have declared the name of a "Source" but I don't really know what this is doing.  Can someone link me to some reading or give me a very high level explanation of what I'm naming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Source property is supposed to define what is logging the event.  It's usually the name of your application, but if you've got something massive it can be some particular module inside your application.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.source%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is always a good place to look for things like this, incidentally.

Answer (score 2):

It is the event originator. Should be your application name.